# Unity 3D on iOS : Working with Compass and Gyroscope

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, sensors, gyroscope, compass

I'd like to make an AR app in Unity. Which displays GeoLocated Points Of interests. 
For now the GPS give me the correct location of the player and the points. 
And the Gyroscope reads well the device rotations.

My issue is I can't rotate the device like it is in the real world.

When I Start the app, it just point to south. I want it to point towards the real direction i'm heading.

for now, I have a very straightforward gyroscope that scripts that works.

```
var x = Input.gyro.rotationRate.x;
var y = Input.gyro.rotationRate.y;
var z = Input.gyro.rotationRate.z;
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (x, y, z);
```

What I want to do is to add the part where I start by heading in the true direction of the player.

Thank you guys.

Comment: not gonna lie. This question is very unclear. Who is "he"? What exactly are you trying to achieve? What code have you tried?

Comment: The device, i'm sorry i'm not a native English speaker. What I want to achieve is to match the rotation of the player in the Unity game to it's real rotation in the world. 
If in the world I'm heading south West, i Want my camera in the game to be heading the same direction.

Comment: I edit the question for the code matter